# cannot import gradle project in oxygen eclipse - error on delombok line

Tags: eclipse, gradle, lombok

I am getting an error in importing an existing gradle project - which has lombok as well, and the error while importing points to lombok line only.

How can I solve this error - so that importing of the project is successful?

If I comment that line - then it works but then lombok does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Java Home Directory shown in the Gradle loading window at the end - if that is shown as unknown then your problem solution is as follows:

In Oxygen-eclipse :
Go to eclipse.ini file and edit above -vmargs as follows:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe<YOUR JDK Path>
```

In any other eclipse version - make sure the Java Home Directory is set properly either using .ini file or via the eclipse preferences menu.